How to add embeddings in already existing Chroma vector store
I have to load and process large number of PDFs and store processed embeddings in vector store. To avoid TPM limitation and other errors and also for the sake of modularity, I want to do it in batches (A batch of 10 PDFs each time).
I have done these steps:

Added list of extracted contents from all PDFs to Docs[]

Thus, Docs contains the combined content from all the PDFs

Created multiple batches (batch_size=10) from Docs[] (each Batch having batch size 10)

Using text_splitter, split each Batch (with chunk_size = 1500 and chunk_overlap = 150) and created Splits


Now I want to process these Splits from all batches and store them in already existing vectorstore. My embedding and vectordb creation looks like this:
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai.api_key)
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embedding)

Then I tried these methods but all of them giving either this or that error:
vectordb.add_documents(splits)

vectordb.add_documents([split], embedding=embedding)

vectordb.add_document(split, embedding)

vectordb.add(embeddings)  

If anyone having idea how to achieve this please share.

use the vectordb.from_text method.  The from_texts() method of the vectordb object is called to create a document storage object.  It returns a document storage object (docstorage) that can be used to store and retrieve documents from the vector database.
loader=PyPDFLoader("attention_is_all_you_need.pdf")
data=loader.load()

chunk_size=200
chunk_overlap=50

splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=chunk_size,
    chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap,
separators=['.']
docs=splitter.split_documents(data)
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=openai.api_key)
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embedding)

vectordb= Chroma (
    persist_directory=persist_directory,
    embedding_function=embedding_function
)

vectordb.persist()
docstorage = vectordb.from_texts(docs,embedding_function)


from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=model,
    chain_type="stuff", retriever=docstorage.as_retriever())

query = "why is the sky blue?"

print(qa.run(query))


If you have done loading and splitting correctly, you should have a list of Documents.
Consider this simple working example:
example_vectorstore = Chroma(
    collection_name='your_collections_name',
    persist_directory=persist_dir,
    embedding_function=embeddings_model
)

docs_in_coll = len(example_vectorstore.get()['documents'])
print(f'Existing docs: {docs_in_coll}')

# add 1 doc
doc1 = Document(page_content='abcd')
example_vectorstore.add_documents([doc1])

